# Trying to explode an array with unnest() in Presto and failing due to extra column

Tags: sql, presto

I have data from a query that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
    model_features
FROM some_db
```

which returns:

```
{
  "food1": 0.65892159938812,
  "food2": 0.90786880254745,
  "food3": 0.88357985019684,
  "food4": 0.99999821186066,
  "food5": 0.99237471818924,
  "food6": 0.62127977609634
}
{
  "food4": 0.9999965429306,
  "text1": 0.82206630706787
}
...
```

etc.

What I am eventually trying to do is simply get a count of each of the "food1", "food2" features,
but to do so (i *think*) I need to trim out the unnecessary numeric data. I'm at a loss as to how to do this, as everytime I try to simply unnest

```sql
SELECT
    t.concepts
FROM some_db
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(model_features) AS t(concepts)
```

I get this error:

`Column alias list has 1 entries but 't' has 2 columns available`

Anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: What does `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(model_features) FROM some_db` gives you?

Comment: that returns `map(varchar, double)`

Answer (score 1):

Solved this for myself: the issue was I needed to avoid dropping the second column of information in order for the query to execute. This may not be the canonical best way to approach, but it worked:

```sql
SELECT
    t.concepts,
    t.probabilities
FROM some_db
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(model_features) AS t(concepts,probabilities)
```

Comment: This is the canonical way of UNNEST-ing a `map`. See the docs https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest ("_maps are expanded into two columns (key, value)_").